# C# decryption: Length of the data to decrypt if invalid error

Tags: c#, encryption

Ok so for a school project I am making an app that has an encryption function.

Here is my code

```
public static string EncryptString(string stringToEncrypt, string hash)
        {
            byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
                using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { 
                    Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
                {
                    ICryptoTransform transform = tripleDES.CreateEncryptor();
                    byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
                }
            }
        }



        public static string DecryptString(string stringToDecrypt, string hash)
        {
            byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToDecrypt);
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
                using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
                {
                    Key = keys,
                    Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                    Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
                })
                {
                    ICryptoTransform transform = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
                    byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
                }
            }
        }
```

Currently the encryption method works, however the decryption method crashes the entire app. The error message is as follows:

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.'

It it important for the app that the user can set their own encryption/decryption key.

What exactly is causing the app to not work? I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that, school project or not, neither MD5 nor 3DES are considered secure algorithms anymore. This is a classic illustration of an old-timey API using old-timey defaults providing a kind of encryption that has no place in an actual app. Whether or not you could replace it with something less volatile and fewer opportunities to shoot yourself in the foot (like Sodium) depends on the purpose of the exercise, I suppose.

Comment: Console.Writeline the length of the data on the line before the exception

Comment: You need to do the opposite actions in the opposite order. The last bit of your encryption routine does Base64 encoding. The first bit of decryption should thus be Base64 decoding, *not* UTF8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should resolve your problem, you just need to decode the base64 string in the decrypt function, ie byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt);.

Also we want to return a string, rather than base64 data, so we'll do UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString() at then end of DecryptString.

I would take note of the fact that this would not be considered secure as the comments above indicate, but this is a learning exercise, so this will get you up and running!

I've also created a DotNetFiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PPzXKo

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace triple_des_test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main() 
        {
            string key = "my key";
            string encrypted = EncryptString("Hello world", key); 
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: " + DecryptString(encrypted, key));
        }

        public static string EncryptString(string stringToEncrypt, string key)
        {
            byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { 
                    Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
                {
                    ICryptoTransform transform = tripleDES.CreateEncryptor();
                    byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        public static string DecryptString(string stringToDecrypt, string key)
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt);
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
                {
                    Key = keys,
                    Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                    Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
                })
                {
                    ICryptoTransform transform = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
                    byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results, 0, results.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution but I am still now getting another error that now says System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Bad Data.
' Any idea what would have caused this?

Comment: Oh yes, that might be a slight discrepancy in the .net versions we're using. What version of C# are you testing with? I'll modify my answer to suit it! I've tested with .Net 4.7 and .Net core 3.1.

Comment: From what I have been able to find the .Net framework I have is v4.0.3. I don't know if this helps.

Comment: Oh great, thank you. I'll see if I can replicate your issue. Are you using the same stringToEncrypt and key?

Comment: Are you using the same key to encrypt and decrypt as well? Thanks!

Comment: Okay turns out I had a persistent piece of encrypted text my method was attempting to decrypt. I have removed it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh great,  glad to hear that.  Happy coding!